# How to output text value of counter in for loop

Tags: loops

Consider following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{i}
\forloop{i}{0}{\value{i} < 3}
{
    % trying to get the text of the counter i i.e. 0 1 2
    % I tried the following and doesn't seem to work
    $\value{i}$
    $\text\value{i}$
}

\end{document}
```

I've looked online and couldn't find anything so hope you can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean with “text value”. It seems like you're looking for `\arabic{i}`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{i}
\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 4}
{
  $\thei$
}

\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 4}
{
  \roman{i}
}

\end{document}
```